# Why can't I inject the ProductRepositoryInterface in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, controllers, dependency-injection, action

I have a controller action into which I would like to inject the product-repository

```
namespace Nosto\Tagging\Controller\Export;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Test extends Action
{

    private $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository    
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
```

No matter what order I put my constructor arguments, Magento's dependency-injection always injects an invalid class for the `productRepository` argument leading PHP to throw and argument error. The `storeManager` getd injected just fine. Clearing the caches haven't helped.

Here is the exception thrown:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Nosto\Tagging\Controller\Export\Test::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface, instance of Nosto\Tagging\Helper\Account given.
```

The class names and argument positions in the error message change but the error definition is always the same. Removing the `ProductRepositoryInterface` from the constructor makes everything fine again.

Comment: Re: "Magento's dependency-injection always injects an invalid class for the productRepository argument"  Including the exact error will help other people diagnose the problem.

Comment: did you clear var/generation?

Comment: @AlanStorm. Sorry about that. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This generally crops up when you add another parameter to the constructor because Magento caches it in var/generation. **You need to clear var/generation** which forces Magento to regenerate the interceptor.

Comment: It seems that you were right. I've been clearing the caches from the admin and that didn't help.

Comment: Looks like in new installation, generated folder is in the root folder structure not in var, might help

Comment: I have created a custom module and trying this code inside Custom\Module\MagentoU\Test class; `public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory, 
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session, 
        \Custom\Module\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $unit1ProductRepository, 
        array $data, 
        $justAParameter = ""
        )`
`<preference for="Custom\Module\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" 
                type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository" />`

Comment: Tried everything still getting the same error **Argument 4 passed to Custom\Module\MagentoU\Test::__construct() must be an instance of Custom\Module\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor given**

Comment: Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` after it

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say without further details, but I'm going to assume youe code sample **actually** looks something like this

```
namespace Packagename\Module\Controller;
class Test extends Action
{

    private $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository    
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
}
```

i.e. with a PHP namespace (since all controllers have namespaces in Magento 2).

If that's the case, then in your code sample you're actually trying to inject a `Packagename\Module\Controller\ProductRepositoryInterface` class.  If you use a class name without a namespace prefix, PHP assumes you want a class in the **current** namespace.

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to inject any module to a controller with this error message. Deleting var/generation worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is running the compile command.

```
/var/www/magento2-root$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2.2 delete folder:

```
"generated/code"
```

And that will solve the problem.